# Nginx - difference between root and alias?

Tags: nginx, alias, documentroot

My goal is to have a Laravel installation running alongside a Nuxt application generated as static content.

I'd like for Laravel to be available, when the location start with `/api`. This works as expected.

For any other requests, I'd like to have Nginx serve me the static content from inside another folder.

I can achieve this by changing the document root at line 18 (`root /var/www/html/public/dist;`) and changing the following `try_files` configuration to what it states in the config below.

I tried switching `root` out for `alias` instead, and that gave me some funky results. I get a 500 server response from Nginx with the following output in the error log:

```
2020/09/29 13:28:17 [error] 7#7: *3 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html", client: 172.21.0.1, server: _, request: "GET /my/fake/url HTTP/1.1", host: "localhost"
172.21.0.1 - - [29/Sep/2020:13:28:17 +0000] "GET /claims/creat HTTP/1.1" 500 580 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/85.0.4183.121 Safari/537.36" "-"
```

I have the following configuration (running inside a Docker container).

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;

    root /var/www/html/public;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    server_name _;

    charset utf-8;

    location = /favicon.ico { log_not_found off; access_log off; }
    location = /robots.txt  { log_not_found off; access_log off; }

    error_page 404 /index.php;

    location / {
        alias /var/www/html/public/dist;
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
        error_page 404 /400.html;
    }

    location ~ /api {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php$is_args$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass php:9000;
        fastcgi_index index.php;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $realpath_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }
    
    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

I'm not entirely sure what the difference is which also makes me question whether I should use `alias` or `root` in my case, and I would appreciate some help with understanding this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem from your error message is with your `try_files`, not your `root` or `alias`. You tried to load a URL path that doesn't exist, and in a normal configuration nginx would just serve a 404 or try to load your web app's front controller. But your `try_files` tells it to serve `/index.html` instead. So it starts over trying to load `/index.html` and ends up at the same `try_files`, but that file doesn't exist either, so it gives the error `rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"` because it was already trying to load `/index.html`.

You should first fix `try_files`. Examples:

```
try_files $uri $uri/ =404;           # static site
try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;     # PHP front controller
```

---

Now, to your secondary question.

`root` specifies the actual document root, the directory on the filesystem to serve static files from, which corresponds to the URL path `/`. For instance, if you have `root /var/www/html/public` and ask for a URL `/css/myapp.css` then this will map to the file path `/var/www/html/public/css/myapp.css`.

`alias` allows you to remap some URL path below the root to some other directory so that you can serve static files from elsewhere. For example, for a `location /static/` you might define `alias /var/www/html/files/`. In this case, instead of going to a subdirectory of the `root`, the `alias` will be substituted for the part of the URL path in the `location`. So `/static/` becomes `/var/www/html/files/` and a request for `/static/myapp.css` will try to load the file `/var/www/html/files/myapp.css` instead of `/var/www/html/public/css/myapp.css`.

It doesn't make sense to use `alias` with `location /`. If necessary to define a different file path here, use `root` (but be aware that this can be an [anti-pattern](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/tutorials/config_pitfalls/#root-inside-location-block)).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I'm not quite sure I understand the `try_files` part though, because it works when I use `root` but not when I use `alias`. The static site works as expected when using `root`. Does that mean my `try_files` is still wrong though?

Comment: @Repox It's fine if you're serving a single page app, but you never mentioned anything to suggest that you are doing that.

Comment: Hi again. Thank you for replying again. My page isn't a single page app, the website is generated with html pages for each possible routes from the static site generator.

Comment: Then go with what is written above in the answer.